# How can i allow access to a record with an assigned user SUITECRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have client records which is restricted to the agent1, agent2, agent3 users. They can only access viewing and editing if they're assigned to it. Ive created an Agent role and configured the client module to owner but the problem is i can't access the client record even though ive assigned it to an agent. It gives me an "NO ACCESS" message an returning me to home page.

Comment: Can the agent access the record that they are assigned to? Just for kicks, try running a Repair Roles. That will fill in any gaps from installing any custom modules.

Comment: yes supposedly if my understanding to suitecrm is correct or there is something im doing wroing ?
ive tried changing the agent roles->view tab to "all" now i can see the record and edit it but when i go to client module in listview, i dont see the record.

Comment: It sounds like once you reassign the record to someone else then you can't access it. Is that correct? The agent you assign it to can access it because it is assigned to them and access for the agent is set to Owner. So far this sounds correct. If you also want access to it then you need greater than owner access. Either All or Group and have a group you belong to assigned to the record.

Comment: yes i use admin user to assign the record to an agent and when i logged as the agent user i cant access that record. security group could help but i was hoping i could override this permission issue programmatically.

Comment: So the agent that you assigned it to cannot access that record? Go to that agent's user record, click on the Access tab, and see what permissions are for that module.

Comment: I think ive found the mistake. I was assigning the wrong agent to the record and using a different agent user to view that record. What a stupid mistake.

Comment: When you post such questions then it will be nice to have a screenshot of configured role (at least for the module where you are facing issue).

Comment: We've all done something like that before. Glad you found it!